# If $\lvert f_1(t)- \sum_{l=1}^N a_l e^{-\lambda_l t} \rvert \leq 2A e^{-t} [1-e^{-\lambda_N t}]$, can I conclude that they are equal? - Revised

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $f_1 : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be smooth function, and we assume the following

1. $f_1(t)=\sum_{l=1}^N A_l(t)$ for some nonnegative smooth functions $A_l(t)$ such that $A_l(0)=a_l>0$.
2. $f_1(t) \leq e^{-t}\sum_{l=1}^N a_l$ for all $t \geq 0$.
3. $f_1(t) \leq \exp(-2C' \lambda_N^3 t) \sum_{l=1}^N a_l$ for all $t \geq 0$ where $C'$ is some positive constant.
4. $\lvert f_1(t)- \sum_{l=1}^N a_l e^{-\lambda_l t} \rvert \leq 2e^{-t} [1-e^{-\lambda_N t}]\sum_{l=1}^N a_l $ for all $t \geq 0$, where $1=\lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_N$ are some given numbers as well.

Then, is it possible to conclude that $f_1(t)=\sum_{l=1}^N a_l e^{-\lambda_l t}$ for all $t \geq 0$? Or at least what can I say about these two functions?

I have tried to use the integral form of the Gronwall inequality but it does not seem to work that much... Could anyone please help me?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html What definition of *smooth function* are we working with here? I suspect the answer is *no* in most cases (most definitions of *smooth*), but this is just my intuition and may well be wrong.

Comment: As a simple counterexample for the equality claim you can choose $f_1(t) = Ae^{-t}$ and $f_2(t) = Ae^{-t}e^{-3t}$.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I oversimplified my original problem...

Comment: I added more conditions. Could you help me once more?

Comment: This still doesn't imply your conclusion, for example if $C' = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda_i = 1$ for all $i$, then $f_1(t) =  e^{-2t}\sum_{l=1}^N a_l$ also satisfies all four conditions. In general you will not get a unique solution from a couple of upper bounds on the function and its distance to another function if those bounds are not chosen specifically to be sharp.

And btw, commenters that didn't write the question/answer don't receive notifications unless you @ them.

Comment: I was about to fix this. $C'$ can be as large as you want and $\lambda_N$ is strictly greater than $\lambda_1$.

Comment: @user23571113 I posted the question on MO instead, with more care and refinement. Perhaps, could you help me there?  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450215/equality-of-two-nonnegative-functions-under-certain-decay-conditions

Comment: The question is completely different to what it was originally. I'm not downvoting, but I'm not longer interested, as I find it oddly specific. To answer the original question, in general, smooth functions are still a wide class of functions.